# calculate log-normal parameters using the mean and var of the given distribution and obtain the mean and var from the generated random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, distribution-theory

Following [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95498/how-to-calculate-log-normal-parameters-using-the-mean-and-std-of-the-given-distr) question, I am trying to estimate the parameters of lognormal dist based on Var and mean, and generate some rand numbers. Then for checking the accuracy, I calculate the mean and var for these random numbers. The point is that the mean matches, but not the var. I think I have misunderstood sth.

Here is my code in R

```
mean=20
var=30
sdl=log(var+1)
meanl=log(mean/sqrt(1+var))
meanlc = meanl
sdlc =  sdl
nn=rlnorm(10000,mean=meanlc,sdl=sdlc)
mean(nn)
log(var(nn)+1)
sd(nn)
var(nn)
log(var(nn))
```

and the output

```
 > mean(nn)
 [1] 952.2693
 > log(var(nn)+1)
 [1] 19.89513
 > sd(nn)
 [1] 20901.25
 > var(nn)
 [1] 436862122
 > log(var(nn))
 [1] 19.89513
```

Comment: Is the 3rd line `sdl=log(var+1)` supposed to be implementing $sd(\log(X)) = \sqrt{\log [(s/m)^2 +1]}$? Where's the square root? In addition, why are you using `var` in place of $(s/m)^2$?  I see you do the same in the 4th line for `meanl`. This is correct only in specific cases and incorrect in general.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake, based on your comment and https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/06/04/simulate-lognormal-data-with-specified-mean-and-variance.html I corrected the code and post it above. Thank you so much for spending time and reading my problem Lee. Please point out my mistake and I will accept that as the answer.

Comment: mean1=20
var1=30
meanlc    = log((mean1*mean1) / sqrt (var1 + (mean1 * mean1)));         
sdlc = sqrt(log((sqrt(var1 + (mean1*mean1))*sqrt(var + (mean1*mean1)))/(mean1* mean1)));  
nn=rlnorm(10000,mean=meanlc,sdl=sdlc);
mean(nn);
var(nn);